# Using Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse to show that two graphs are distinguishable

Tags: logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic

We have two structures $A$: an infinite clique and $B_n$ and a clique of size $n+1$.
To my eye, duplicator has winning strategy in game with $n$ rounds.   Simply, duplicator copies moves of spoiler. It is possible, after each move - newly chosen vertex has the same number of related (chosen before) verticles.

However,  Is it possible. I think that I can't see something wrong in my reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is sound. Indeed, no matter what vertices are chosen by either player, after $k$ rounds, both graphs will be cliques of size $k$, hence order isomorphic.

Comment: Could you help me also here :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041592/show-non-definability-of-biparted-graphs-graphs-with-eulerian-cycle-even-numb?noredirect=1#comment4191122_2041592  (the same problems)