# Show non-definability of (biparted graphs, graphs with eulerian cycle, even number of nodes)

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

As you can see I am woring at three excercises:
Prove that following classes for graphs are non-definiable (on FO sentence):
a) biparted graphs
b) even number of nodes
c) graphs contains eulerian cycle

a) We know that biparted graphs can't contain odd cycle.  So lets $n$ will be number of rounds. Now, Let $A$ will be cycle (biparted graph) of length $2^{n}+2$ and $B$ will be cycle of length $2^n+1$. We know, that in $n$ rounds duplicator has winning stratrgy.
b) Similar apporach as in (a).  Two chains of lenght $2^n+2$ and $2^n+1$.
c)  This one seems to be the hardest.  I think that we can give two structures for $n$ rounds:
$A$ is cycle of length $2^{n+1}$ and $B$ is chain of length $2^{n+1}$

Am I ok ?

Comment: What is a "duplicator"?

Comment: duplicator it is player II in EF game

Comment: I don't know much about EF games, but so far your problems fall to plain compactness. It's probably better for you to get well acquainted with how to compactness to its full potential before learning about other tools.

Comment: Yes, but using EF games I can show that some class is not definiable (only **one** first order sentence express this class). When it comes to axiomatizaiotn we can use infinite set

Comment: My answer is a counter-example to your implicit claim that compactness cannot be used for definability. In fact if you think carefully about what I say in my answer it should be obvious that compactness is much easier to use for definability than axiomatizability!

Comment: Yes, my implicit comment suggest that I think that compactness cant be used for definability.  What about (a). These graphs are axiomatizable and non-definiable ? Yeah ?

Comment: Yes that's the intended conclusion you're supposed to arrive at **after** thinking carefully through my answer. Axiomatizable does not imply definable. It's not wise to hurry when it comes to logic. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Hints

(a) Construct a set $S$ of axioms saying "$G$ is not bipartite and every vertex in $G$ has exactly two neighbours." What graphs satisfy $S$? Now add a set $T$ of axioms that force $G$ to have no cycles, and use compactness on $S \cup T$.

(a*) Note that "$G$ is bipartite" is axiomatizable. Why? And where does the proof of (a) fail to show that it is not axiomatizable?

(b) Even implies finite. So following the same method described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2000751/21820) leads to a proof.

(c) Eulerian cycle also implies finite. So same as (b).

Comment: lets note that I am not consider axiomatiation - I consider if these classes are definiable(what means that we can express this class (here bipartie graphs) with **one** first order sentence.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I am in hurry.  When it comes to (a) I will try the bug in your "proof. When it comes (b) and (c) - what does it mean 'implies finite'

Comment: @HaskellFun: Only finite graphs can have even number of nodes.

Comment: So what do you think about my reasoning in question -  I mean reasoning with EF games

Comment: @HaskellFun: I don't know much about EF games, so I'll not comment on that.

Comment: So, is it possible to show non-definibilty using compactness theorem ? I know that if sentence is not axiomatizable then it is also not definiable, but (for example (a)) we know that biparite graphs are axiomatizable but not definiable

Comment: @HaskellFun: I don't get what you're saying in your last sentence. There is nothing wrong with both halves.

Comment: Did you manage to using compactness theorem show that bipartie graph are not definiable (one sentence)

Comment: @HaskellFun: Work through my answer to figure out. I don't like it when people ask for spoon-feeding.

Comment: Ok, I will try to dicover your mystery!

Comment: Genrally I don't understand your (a). After all your $S$ states that graph is not bipartied.  To show that bipartied graphs are not  axiomatizable using compactness theorem you should assume that there exists $S$ such that graph is bipartied.   So I don't know where proof fails, for me this proof doesnt try to prove that bipartied graphs are not axiomatized.   BTW, is it possible to axiomatize that graph doesn't contain cycle ?

Comment: Moreover, when it comes to (b) part. It is axiomatized.After all, we can express that graph has exatly $k$ nodes. So, we may axiomatized it with: $\Delta=\{\phi_{2i}|i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ where $\phi_i:$ there are exists **exactly** $i$ nodes.

Comment: @HaskellFun: Your question (a) asks to prove that "bipartite" is not definable. My argument proceeds by contradiction, if you didn't realize. Using the assumption that "bipartite" is definable we can construct $S$ and then later reach a contradiction. And yes whatever I explicitly ask you to do is possible. As for (b), your set of sentences says that it has exactly 0 nodes and also exactly 2 nodes and also ..., so it axiomatizes the empty class of graphs! If you follow the proof method in the link you will prove that "even number of nodes" is **not** axiomatizable.

Comment: When it comes to even numbet of nodes - of course you are right.   Using compactness is ok, because we would like arbitraly big structure accept.  It is sufficient to extends set by sentences: $\{\phi_0, \phi_2, \phi_4,....\}$ where $\phi_i$ states: "there are exists at least $i$ nodes in graph". In real $i$ may be any - not neccessarily even.